# PHP - Uploaded file is zero bytes

Tags: php, linux, upload

I'm trying to set up an upload script on my VPS, and I'm having some trouble getting the `php.ini` settings right. When I upload the script, PHP receives the file no problem, and says it's at `/tmp/phpNAMEHERE`. The destination folder is being populated with moved files, but because the source path doesn't exist, it's not moving anything into the file. I used `file_exists()` on `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` and discovered that the file doesn't exist at time of execution. This implies that the path in `tmp_name` is wrong.

I checked my PHP info page:

**upload_tmp_dir**: /tmp

**post_max_size**: 64M

**upload_max_filesize**: 64M (my file is roughly 4MB)

**max_execution_time**: 300

**max_input_time**: 300

I'm fairly certain all the settings are correct!

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm...tough one, charset of the file as opposed to the server?

Comment: Would that apply to images? (That's all I'm uploading.)